# Elegant way of fetching multiple objects in custom order

Tags: django, django-queryset

What's an elegant way for fetching multiple objects in some custom order from a DB in django?

For example, suppose you have a few products, each with its name, and you want to fetch three of them to display in a row on your website page, in some fixed custom order. Suppose the names of the products which you want to display are, in order: `["Milk", "Chocolate", "Juice"]`

One could do

```
unordered_products = Product.objects.filter(name__in=["Milk", "Chocolate", "Juice"])
products = [
   unordered_products.filter(name="Milk")[0],
   unordered_products.filter(name="Chocolate")[0],
   unordered_products.filter(name="Juice")[0],
]
```

And the post-fetch ordering part could be improved to use a `name`-indexed dictionary instead:

```
ordered_product_names = ["Milk", "Chocolate", "Juice"]
products_by_name = dict((x.name, x) for x in unordered_products)
products = [products_by_name[name] for name in ordered_product_names]
```

But is there a more elegant way? e.g., convey the desired order to the DB layer somehow, or return the products grouped by their name (aggregation seems to be similar to what I want, but I want the actual objects, not statistics about them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order your product by a custom order with only one query of your ORM (executing one SQL query only):

```
ordered_products = Product.objects.filter(
    name__in=['Milk', 'Chocolate', 'Juice']
).annotate(
    order=Case(
        When(name='Milk', then=Value(0)),
        When(name='Chocolate', then=Value(1)),
        When(name='Juice', then=Value(2)),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('order')
```

## Update

### Note

Speaking about "elegant way" (and best practice) I think `extra` method (proposed by @Satendra) is absolutely to avoid.

Official Django documentation report this about [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra) :

> **Warning**
>
> You should be very careful whenever you use **extra()**. Every time you
>   use it, you should escape any parameters that the user can control by
>   using **params** in order to protect against SQL injection attacks .
>   Please read more about [SQL injection protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection).

### Optimized version

If you want to handle more items whit only one query you can change my first query and use the Django ORM flexibility as suggested by @Shubhanshu in his answer:

```
products = ['Milk', 'Chocolate', 'Juice']
ordered_products = Product.objects.filter(
    name__in=products
).order_by(Case(
    *[When(name=n, then=i) for i, n in enumerate(products)],
    output_field=IntegerField(),
))
```

The output of this command will be similar to this:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Milk >, <Product: Chocolate>, <Product: Juice>]>
```

And the SQL generated by the ORM will be like this:

```
SELECT "id", "name"
FROM "products"
WHERE "name" IN ('Milk', 'Chocolate', 'Juice')
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN "name" = 'Milk' THEN 0
    WHEN "name" = 'Chocolate' THEN 1
    WHEN "name" = 'Juice' THEN 2
    ELSE NULL
END ASC
```

Comment: It would be cool if you made the final step and refactored this into a function or a method of a manager mixin.

Answer (score 3):

When there is no relation between the objects that you are fetching and you still wish to fetch (or arrange) them in certain (custom) order, you may try doing this:

```
unordered_products = Product.objects.filter(name__in=["Milk", "Chocolate", "Juice"])

product_order = ["Milk", "Chocolate", "Juice"]

preserved = Case(*[When(name=name, then=pos) for pos, name in enumerate(product_order)])

ordered_products = unordered_products.order_by(preserved)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice answer, but pretty similar to the dict method above. I am hoping for something in Django which would help avoid such post-fetch pythonic twiddling.

Comment: I take my previous comment back, since this doesn't perform the fetch and then twiddle with it - it actually modifies the ORM access which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad that you got what you were looking for. Only thing being: my answer performs the same computation in a much more condensed way then what is being done in the accepted answer written by @Paolo. And thanks to him for addressing my answer in his answer :)

Comment: I accepted @Paolo's answer because his final optimized version is more concise and he made extra effort to show the output SQL. However, you definitely deserve a big credit here as well. Thank you!

Comment: I completely understand your point. Will keep this thing in mind while answering questions in future. Thanks for the due credit!

Answer (score 0):

Try this into meta class from model:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('name', 'related__name', )
```

this get your records ordered by your specified field's

then: chocolate, chocolate blue, chocolate white, juice green, juice XXX, milk, milky, milk YYYY  should keep that order when you fetch

Comment: That only works for an alphabetical, non-custom order.

Answer (score 0):

### [Creating a QuerySet from a list while preserving order](https://codybonney.com/creating-a-queryset-from-a-list-while-preserving-order-using-django/)

This means the order of output QuerySet  will be same as the order of list used to filter it.

> The solution is more or less same as [@PaoloMelchiorre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755343/paolo-melchiorre) answer
>
> But if there are more items lets say *1000 products* in
> `product_names` then you don't have to worry about adding more conditions in [**`Case`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case), you can use **[`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra)** method of QuerySet

```
product_names = ["Milk", "Chocolate", "Juice", ...]

clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN name=%s THEN %s' % (name, i) for i, name in enumerate(product_names)])  
ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses  

queryset = Product.objects.filter(name__in=product_names).extra(  
           select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
# Output: <QuerySet [<Product: Milk >, <Product: Chocolate>, <Product: Juice>,...]>
```

Comment: Good to see another similar way to what @PaoloMelchiorre suggested. Is there am actual limit to the number of `When`s in a `Case` in Django, though? If not, then it looks like both methods could be encapsulated in functions which would work for an arbitrary number of fetched objects.

Comment: @Danra, No there is no limit, [Case()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) accepts any number of When() objects as individual arguments,  Other options are provided using keyword arguments.

Comment: As i reported in my answer update, `extra` method is to avoid.
You can do the same thing with the Django ORM methods.

Comment: @PaoloMelchiorre Ok got it, thanks for adding this information, but Sometimes, the Django query syntax by itself can’t easily express a complex WHERE clause. For these edge cases, Django provides the extra() QuerySet modifier — a hook for injecting specific clauses into the SQL generated by a QuerySet.

Comment: @Satendra I am aware that `extra` is a powerful method, but it can also be very dangerous and in this specific case it is not necessary.